# Object-Oriented JS - without global variables?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am taking an object-oriented approach to building a Javascript app.
For starters, I am creating a Game object and a Timer object.

Here's my current implementation:
The Timer object has the following methods:

```
setTimerValue()  
start()  
stop()  
getTimeLeft()  
timeExpired()
```

The Game object has the following methods:

```
reset()
run()
...
```

`Timer.start()` uses `window.setInterval()` to start the countdown. 
When the countdown gets to zero, it calls `Timer.timeExpired()`.

`Timer.timeExpired()` announces that the game is over and should call `Game.reset()` and  `Game.run()` to restart the game. But how can this be done when the Timer object doesn't know anything about the Game object?

Does the Game object need to be a global variable for this to work?

Also, the Game object currently has a Timer object as one of its properties. This allows the Game object to call the Timer methods. But unclear on how Timer methods can call the Game object.

I have a nagging suspicion that I am creating too many dependencies between the objects and could use some suggestions on how to architect this better.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't believe people when they say "globals are evil". *They're not.* There are situations where it is distinctly desirable to have globals. This sort of a case is one where it makes a lot of sense to use a global.

Comment: My question is a more general one. In order for object A to call object B's methods and vice-versa, do both need to be global variables?

Comment: Of course not. But they do need to be able to get a reference to the other.

Comment: Two objects can call each other without either one being a global variable.  Each object just has to store a reference to any object (in its own instance data) that it wants to be able to call methods on.  It can do that my creating such an object and saving its reference (which sounds appropriate for the game object to have a timer object in it).  Or, two objects can be told about one another and they can save a reference which they can later call.

Comment: (Your response states why I made it a comment rather than an answer.) No, they merely need to have a reference to each other - that can be in their own scope, inside their objects, or a global, or even via other lookups if you want.

Comment: How do you pass a "reference" of Object A to Object B (and vice-versa)?

Comment: @JMan objects in javascript are passed by reference, exceptions are the primitive types (int, string) which are passed by value

Comment: Not a good design pattern - google for "coupling" and "cohesion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an event driven approach or the observer design pattern. Javascript has one of the flexible event driven implementation from my experience.
So you have the Timer object which doesn't really have to know about any other objects. 
When you call Timer.start(), the object should emit a custom event, like "timerStarted", likewise for the other methods:

```
Timer.stop() - > emits "timerStoped"
Timer.timeExpired() -> emits "timerExpired"
```

For every event raised by the Timer, there should be an event handler, which will be called when the coresponding event is fired.

If you use jquery, handling events should be trivial:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
var timer = new Timer();
var game  = new Game();

$(timer).bind('timerStarted', function(e) {
    game.doSomething();
});
```

in the Timer::start() you should write:

```
start: function() {
    $(this).trigger('timerStarted');
}
```

Another approach is using callbacks:
If you want something to be done when the timer starts, you could pass a lambda function to the start method of the timer:

```
// timer method
start: function(callback) {
    if(typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}

// main logic
var timer = new Timer();
var game  = new Game();

timer.start(function() {
    game.doSomething();
});
```

I hope you get the ideea